# Windows is not genuine, no memory

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory

I bought this Toshiba Protege refurbished from a third party dealer off of Amazon, will not do  again. Since purchasing it, all we have had are issues.

But the biggest one is the one I am having now. This computer is about to become paper weight because the so called company installed Windows 7 Ultimate when it is supposed to be Home Premium. I have the key for the Premium but was never given one for the Ultimate.

Amazon and myself have been trying to get a hold of the seller and he is not returning e-mails and phone calls.  All I am asking from him is the disc and key for the Ultimate.

I am unable to update and it is getting very frustrating.  Plus, there is absolutely no memory left in this thing.  I am beginning to think it was a horrible mistake to get a Toshiba  since we owned an Acer prior with absolutely no memory problems.

Is there anyone who can help me with these issues?  The biggest one is the Window's Key.  I really do not want to throw $500 down the drain especially since I've only had this thing for a little under a year.

Will I need to get Windows Premium software?  Will it come with a Key?  Anyone know how much it will cost me?

Comment: Your post is too verbose so  let me get this straight, you have a laptop that has Windows 7 Ultimate installed but not activated ?You also own a serial key for Windows Premium ?Do you also mean Hard disk space when you say memory ?

Comment: you need to clarify these points, as in the current state your question will be closed as it doesn't make much sense

Comment: Just an easy and simple advice that you can download the Home Premium Image from Microsoft and then burn it on disc or USB and install it, now you can use your key. ISO image will be free available at MS download sites just a little google search. :)

Comment: Shakehar: Yes, it is a laptop with Windows Premium but who I bought it from installed Ultimate. The bottom of the laptop has a premium key, not an ultimate. The hard disk space is already full and I hardly have anything on it because I put it on an external hard drive.

Comment: The laptop also was not sent with an owners manual.  It is a Toshiba Protege R835-P50X.  It does have a SATA USB included.  I am not sure whether or not I can use a SATA with this.  Best Buy said "No".  I do have a Seagate 1 Tb external that I use for memory but I cannot download anything without it.

Comment: I do apologize for any confusion with the question!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you already have a Windows Home Premium key.  If you don't know the key for your current install, install [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html) and it will reveal the key of your current installation.

**If you do not have a current valid key, you need to buy one.**

Then, go [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c0e78d7a-883d-4caa-a8c0-1e127a14612a/windows-7-home-premium-download?forum=w7itproinstall) and download the Windows 7 Home Premium ISO.

**If you do not have space to store the 2GB ISO file, you need to delete files or buy another external hard drive or flash drive to store it temporarily.**

Get the 64-bit edition.  Burn it to a DVD.  If you do not have a program to burn CDs with, download [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download), install it, and use the "Burn Image" option.  The site at that link provides some details.

You now have a Windows 7 Home Premium disc.  Boot from it, and you'll be in Windows Setup.  Follow the prompts to reinstall Home Premium on it, and use your valid Home Premium key.

If you do not feel like spending the money to buy a key, install Linux.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is nothing wrong with the hardware specs, save that the hard drive is full of junk.  (The question is what is this junk).  I googled that particular computer, and while certainly not top-of-the-line, its quite capable of running typical day-to-day stuff.

I assume the Windows Premium key is on the bottom of the laptop, as is typical with most laptops.   If this is the case you almost certainly have a license for Windows Premium - and one which can't be [legally, according to the EULA] transferred to other devices.

As others have said, jump online, download a copy of Windows Premium OEM, do a clean install,  use your license key from the back of the PC and you should be away.

If you can't find a copy of the media on the web - which should be possible - there are plenty of ways of getting it through Torrenting (assuming you don't have a friend with a copy).  Doing this is legal, as you are only getting the media to install software you already have a license to (provided all you are downloading is the media, not a pirated or cracked copy).